# Scheme get operator to be a procedure from a list

Tags: list, scheme, operators

I want to get a operator from a list where it will be a procedure instead of a symbol.

So for example lets say I want to build this list: `'(- a 3)` using `cons`.

If I were to put `((car '(- a 3)) 5 3)`, it should print out `2`. However, since the `-` is inside the list, getting the `car` of the list will still be a symbol instead of the actual operator.

The catch here is that I have to use `cons` to build the `(- a 3)` list (and print it out). My professor will add `car` in front of it along with the `5 3` at the end it should print out `2`.

So I have this currently: `(cons '- (cons 'a (cons '3 '())))`, which prints out `(- a 3)`.

If I add the `car` and `5 3`: `((car (cons '- (cons 'a (cons '3 '())))) 5 3)`, I get an error saying `not a procedure`.

Can someone provide some guidance? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You would need a function which, given a symbol, returns the value globally bound to that symbol.

Comment: Is there such a function already in Scheme? I'm not allowed to make my own.

Comment: Quote prevents normal evaluation, here you want to force it. So... eval

Comment: @coredump- Or don't quote in the first place. The OP said they have to use `cons`, not that they have to quote everything.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That's right, I focused too much on the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use: `(cons - (cons 'a (cons 3 '())))`. That is, don't quote the `-`. That will use the `-` procedure rather than symbol.

```
> ((car (cons - (cons 'a (cons 3 '())))) 5 3)
2
```

This can be written as a quasiquoted list, as a shorthand:<sup>†</sup>

```
> ((car `(,- a 3)) 5 3)
2
```

<sup>†</sup> In a quasiquoted datum—that is, using a backquote instead of a quote—anything with a comma in front is unquoted. (A quasiquote with no commas inside is the same as a quote.)

Comment: Thank you! Never knew about quasiquotes, looks very useful.